# DB2 driver class connot be resolved in persistence.xml and getting entityManager exception

Tags: hibernate, db2, websphere

I am given a project and I have to make it run in my local machine.

It has actually many projects that compile into jar files and a main project that compiles to ear including those jars.

The application is run on WebSphere server and although it runs I eventually get an error concerning the entity manager. Logs are not displaying anything but after debugging, when calling a method from a class from a specific jar, I am getting the following exception:

> javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: 
>       The com.xxx.xxx.managers.xxxManager/entityManager reference of type 
>       javax.persistence.EntityManager for the XXXManager component in the 
>       xxx-managers.jar module of the XXXPortal_ear application cannot be resolved.

After inspecting further I saw that IntelliJ marks my persistence.xml with some errors:

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
<!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup"/> -->
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform" />
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="XXX_TRANSACTIONS"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
<property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="100"/>
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>      
<!-- OpenJPA -->
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="XXX_TRANSACTIONS"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=True, PrettyPrint=true" />
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=DEBUG, Runtime=TRACE, Tool=INFO, Query=TRACE, JDBC=ERROR, SQL=ERROR" />
```

The XXX_TRANSACTIONS values of the property hibernate.default_schema is marked with red and hovering displays:

> Cannot resolve schema 'XXX_TRANSACTIONS'

Also, at the hibernate.connection.driver_class property, part of the value "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource" is marked red (only db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource is red).

Hovering displays:

> Cannot resolve class 'DB2XADataSource'

I tried importing db2jcc.jar but then I get

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource' is not assignable to 'java.sql.Driver'

at the driver class property.

There might be a chance that I messed something up in the WebSphere configuration.

I can provide further information if needed.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Those are lines from the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="XxxModel">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>XxxDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>...
```

I am also posting the General properties of the JDBC provider of WebSphere:

[image]

@Andy Guibert: sadly I cannot upgrade the Hibernate version, it could cause problems when we redeploy to the customer so I cannot perform major changes.

I have to mention that the application works on an other machine. It is opened in the Rational Application Developer Studio (eclipse version for IBM). I am trying to setup on my local machine on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition. One difference that I spotted is that the jar created in my environment did not include the persistence.xml and other resource files of that particular module. I used the maven resources plugin to included in my jar:

```
    <resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>src/main/java/META-INF</directory>
      </resource>
  </resources>
```

Despite that, the problem persist and while debbuging I am still getting the exception that I wrote at the original post.

Comment: Can we see your persistence.xml?  Also, how are you bootstrapping JPA?  Are you trying to use injection (@PersistenceContext / @PersistenceUnit) or are you using javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()?

Also, the "openjpa.jdbc.Schema" property overrides the connection's default schema, which is usually the username associated with the connection (can vary by db vendor) -- if you need to override it, be sure to use a value you intend to use.

Comment: persistencexml is the one I posted in the original post. JPA is set by @PersistenceContext. I have to specify that the application runs as is in an other system, I am just trying to configure it in my local machine so there is no problem to the application, the problem is with my configuration. About the datasources I setup the connections and the default_schema no longer causes an error. The is only the issue with the com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `hibernate.connection.driver_class` property is for your JDBC driver's implementation class of the `java.sql.Driver` class, but you have listed `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource`, which is DB2's implementation of `java.sql.XADataSource`, not its implementation of `java.sql.Driver`.

In any case, I would not recommend that you configure Hibernate this way on WebSphere, because when you configure Hibernate to look directly at a driver class it will bypass WebSphere's connection pool and you will have lesser performance.

Instead, I would recommend configuring a DataSource in WebSphere, and then reference the DataSource JNDI name in your persistence.xml like this:

```
<persistence ...>

  <persistence-unit name="SOME_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/YOUR_DATASOURCE</jta-data-source>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Note that as of Hibernate 5.2.17.Final, Hibernate has a new transaction integration class that is capable of fully integrating with the WebSphere (traditional or Liberty) transaction manager.  If you are using this version or newer, then it is not necessary to `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform`